# Increasing threads of python web scraping script does not increase request rate

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've written a web scraping script in python, which utilises the requests module to send http requests. I am currently averaging around 100 requests per second, but I want to achieve ~ 500 requests per second. I've included a simplified version of the code:

```
import threading, requests, queue

thread_count = 200

def main():
    ses = requests.Session()
    while True:
        url = urls1.get()
        try:
            resp = ses.get(url, timeout=5)
        except:
            urls1.put(url)
            continue

for i in range(thread_count):
    threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

My initial thought were that increasing the thread count should increase the number of requests I can send per second, but I found that no matter how much I increase it, I cant seem to exceed 100 requests per second. I am running this code on a VPS, with sufficient resources and bandwidth, so that can't be the issue. I've also tried to implement this asynchronously, with the HTTPX module, but I achieve similar results

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks